# C: One malloced block for multiple structs of different types

Tags: c

Trying to use one malloc()ed block to store multiple structs of varying types in it. Members are fictitious for demonstration purposes. No assumptions can be made about their type, order, etc., except that they make up perfectly legal C structs which are complete ( fully known by and defined for C compiler). This time its this, the other time is that. I am after the concept. Create your own mix, but the idea must be the same - header struct has pointers to other structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    int    a;
} s1_t;

typedef struct
{
    int    b;
} s2_t;

typedef struct
{
    int    c;
} s3_t;

typedef struct
{
    s1_t*    s1;
    s2_t*    s2;
    s3_t*    s3;
} hdr_t;

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    void*    mem = malloc( sizeof( hdr_t ) + 
                           sizeof( s1_t ) + 
                           sizeof( s2_t ) + 
                           sizeof( s3_t ) );

    hdr_t    hdr = ( hdr_t* )mem;

    hdr->s1 = (s1_t* ) ( hdr + sizeof( hdr ) );
    hdr->s2 = (s2_t* ) ( hdr->s1 + sizeof( s1_t ) );
    hdr->s3 = (s3_t* ) ( hdr->s2 + sizeof( s2_t ) );

    /* etc. */
}
```

Above (naive) code is a hope to not fragment the heap with small mallocs but rather get one block for entire (known at keyboard time) set.

Question: For as portable solution as possible do I have to manually align structs in my scheme?

In other words do I need to (pseudo-code), ALSZ = alignment size for this chip:

```
mem = malloc( hdrsz + ALSZ + s1sz + ALSZ + s2sz + ALSZ + s3sz );

hdr = ( hdr_t* )hdr;

s1 = align( hdr + sizeof( hdr_t ), ALSZ );

s2 = align( s1 + sizeof( s1 ), ALSZ );

s3 = align( s2 + sizeof( s2 ), ALSZ );
```

align( mem, boundary ) is my routine to calculate aligned address.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why can't you use an union? It would manage everything by itself.

Comment: Unions are a way to interpret one memory location in many ways. Its usage pattern is "one of". Not going to work for me. My usage pattern is "each one".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
typedef struct
{
    s1_t*    s1;
    s2_t*    s2;
    s3_t*    s3;
} hdr_t;
```

use

```
typedef struct
{
    s1_t    s1;
    s2_t    s2;
    s3_t    s3;
} hdr_t;

main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    void*    mem = malloc( sizeof( hdr_t ));

    hdr_t*    hdr = ( hdr_t* )mem;
}
```

This achieves exactly what you're looking for: contiguous allocation of memory for a set of structure and a guarantee that the members of `hdr_t` are pointing to the correct location with no worries about chip memory alignment padding;

Comment: +1 this is a nice solution in the case where you have a fixed number of known structs.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer arithmetic is faulty. Adding 1 to a pointer does not advance it by one byte, but to the next element; by the size of the pointed type.

If you have

```
struct foo {
    ...
};

struct bar {
    ...
};

struct baz {
    ...
};

struct header {
    ...
    struct foo *foo;
    struct bar *bar;
    struct baz *baz;
    ...
};
```

you can allocate the structures using a single memory block using

```
struct header *ptr;

ptr = malloc (sizeof (struct header) + sizeof (struct foo) + sizeof (struct bar) + sizeof (struct baz));
if (!ptr) {
    /* out of memory */
    exit(1);
}

ptr->foo = (struct foo *)(ptr + 1);
ptr->bar = (struct bar *)(ptr->foo + 1);
ptr->baz = (struct baz *)(ptr->bar + 1);
```

Alternatively, if you wish to work with byte offsets (for example, if the sizes of the structures are dynamic -- quite legal in C99), you can use

```
struct header *ptr;
char          *tmp;

tmp = malloc (sizeof (struct header) + sizeof (struct foo) + sizeof (struct bar) + sizeof (struct baz));
if (!tmp) {
    /* out of memory */
    exit(1);
}

ptr = (struct header *)tmp;
ptr->foo = (struct foo *)(tmp + sizeof (struct header));
ptr->bar = (struct bar *)(tmp + sizeof (struct header) + sizeof (struct foo));
ptr->baz = (struct baz *)(tmp + sizeof (struct header) + sizeof (struct foo) + sizeof (struct bar));
```

In both cases the pointers in the `struct header` structure will get the same values relative to the pointer of the `struct header` itself. In the latter case, you must also remember to align the new pointers per ABI requirements, if you use arbitrary structure sizes.

Comment: My bad. I wasn't very clear. When I said "no assumptions about struct members" what I meant is that they ARE valid C structs but they are defined elsewhere. I do not know their definitions. All I have access to is custom S1SizeOf(), S2SizeOf(), etc. routines. I do the mallocing, users "paste" their structs in there later. R.'s reply is closest to what I intend to do. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning. Basically the objective is to have one place and enough room and good alignment for custom types of which only sizes are known via their custom typeSizeOf() routines.

Comment: 600 chars is not enough! Anyaway. One place, enough size and good alignment, good old C custom structs defined elsewhere, and later pasted into alotted spots within malloced buffer. I do not know WHAT they are, but I do know that they are structs. Hence the original question. To align or to not align.

Answer (score 0):

Dancrumb's solution is definitely the best if you can use it. If not (for example, if the number of structs you need is variable or there are too many combinations or special-casing is prohibitively costly), you can do the alignment yourself:

Since the alignment requirement of any type always divides the size of the type, start out by taking the LCM of all the types that might appear in your structures. If you want to be lazy, just take the product `sizeof(short)*sizeof(int)*sizeof(long)*...` for all types. Or just use a large power of two like 64 that you're sure is larger than the size of any of them.

Then, when doing pointer arithmetic on the block obtained by malloc, round up the size of each structure to the next multiple of the alignment value you chose above. For example

```
#define ROUND_UP(n, a) (((n)+((a)-1))/(a)*(a))
ps2 = (void *) ( (char *)ps1 + ROUND_UP(sizeof(*ps1), ALIGNMENT) );
```

where `ps1` is the pointer to the first struct in the malloc'd block and `ps2` is the pointer to the second one.

Of course you need to do the same rounding-up when making the allocation to ensure there's sufficient space.

**Edit:** I found an improvement to this in one of my old answers. Since it's a pain to try to figure out the maximum possible alignment requirement, especially if you want to be 100% portable, just use the fact that the alignment requirement of **any type** (including structures) must divide the size of the type, and assume they're equal. That is:

```
ps2 = (void *) ( (char *)ps1 + ROUND_UP(sizeof(*ps1), sizeof(*ps2)) );
```

which rounds up the size of the first struct to the next multiple of the size of the second struct. This may be a bit wasteful, but it's simple and should always work.

Comment: Some weird comments placing. I meant for my previous ones to go at the bottom of the page. Can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: Some more fat fingering. Gosh! Can someone teach me how to type? Anyway. Thanks everyone for your input. I think R.'s answer is the closest one to what I need. To sum it up. Yes. I do need to align things manually for most portable solution.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow me to up R.'s suggestion. So here it goes. +1 for R..

Comment: I see. Similar to what C compiler does to a structure so that it can be used in an array?