# How to Concatenate Multiple Structs within One Block of Memory?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, memcpy

I'm writing in a program in Standard C.  I have a number of defined structs, all of different sizes:

```
typedef struct innerDataStruct{
        int d1, d2;
}dataStruct;
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
typedef struct structA{
        dataStruct data;
}hdrA;
typedef struct structB{
        int d1, d2, d3;
}hdrB;
typedef struct structC{
        int d1;
}hdrC;
```

I need to allocate and populate one hdrA, hdrB, and hdrC struct, then concatenate them into one big chunk of memory.  Also, I’m required to allocate all of my memory ***on the heap***, not the local stack.

(I suppose I could go through each struct and copy each element one-by-one, but that’s a pain.  Also, the structs may be modified later in the future, and I don’t want to have to rewrite my code if that happens.  It would be better to copy the whole structs directly into the big chunk of memory.)

Here is the solution that I thought might work:

```
int* makeBigChunk( hdrA* A, hdrB* B, hdrC* C ){

        size_t size = sizeof( hdrA ) + sizeof( hdrB ) + sizeof( hdrC );

        int* bigChunk = malloc( size );
        bzero( bigChunk, size );

        int iter = 0;
        memcpy( bigChunk+iter, A, sizeof( hdrA ) );
        iter += sizeof( hdrA );
        memcpy( bigChunk+iter, B, sizeof( hdrB ) );
        iter += sizeof( hdrB );
        memcpy( bigChunk+iter, C, sizeof( hdrC ) );

        return bigChunk;
}

void printBigChunk( int* bc ){
        size_t size = sizeof( hdrA ) + sizeof( hdrB ) + sizeof( hdrC );
        printf("Big Chunk of Memory is :: %ld bytes:\n", size);
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < size; i++){
                printf("%d ", *(bc+i));
        }
        printf("\n");
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ){

        hdrA* AAA = malloc( sizeof(hdrA) );
        hdrB* BBB = malloc( sizeof(hdrB) );
        hdrC* CCC = malloc( sizeof(hdrC) );

        AAA->data.d1 = 1;       AAA->data.d2 = 2;
        BBB->d1 = 10;           BBB->d2 = 20;   BBB->d3 = 30;
        CCC->d1 = 100;

        int* bigChunk = makeBigChunk( AAA, BBB, CCC );
        printBigChunk( bigChunk );

        free( bigChunk );
        free( AAA );
        free( BBB );
        free( CCC );

        printf("END OF PROGRAM.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I was hoping the output would be this:

```
Big Chunk of Memory is :: 6 bytes:
1 2 10 20 30 100
END OF PROGRAM.
```

But the actual output is not very inspiring:

```
Big Chunk of Memory is :: 24 bytes:
1 2 0 0 0 0 1041 0 540155953 540024880 540024880 825503793 891301920 892416052 859126069 808727840 942944816 891301944 842018868 808990772 892483616 926101557 941634361 808661305
END OF PROGRAM.
```

So I’m guessing that I have two problems here:  First, when I `memcpy()` each struct into `bigChunk`, I use this iteration system:

```
int iter = 0;
memcpy( bigChunk+iter, A, sizeof( hdrA ) );
iter += sizeof( hdrA );
memcpy( bigChunk+iter, B, sizeof( hdrB ) );
iter += sizeof( hdrB );
memcpy( bigChunk+iter, C, sizeof( hdrC ) );
```

I thought that was pretty clever when I wrote it, but clearly something’s not right.  But I’m not sure what.  Second, I think my `printBigChunk()` function is iterating through `bigChunk` correctly.  It has obviously overcounted the amount of actual memory that I need.

Does anyone see where I’m going wrong?  Is this a struct padding issue or something?  I am not permitted to alter the structs, unfortunately.  Thanks!

EDIT:  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182588/c-one-malloced-block-for-multiple-structs-of-different-types) is sort of what I want to do, but not exactly.  And I was not able to adapt this to my code.

Comment: So you want to work on a platform where `sizeof(int) == 1`?

Comment: Why don't you just make a struct that contains all of the other structs and allocate *that*?

Comment: @MikeCAT No, not necessarily.  I'm coding on a Linux machine with GCC.  What makes you say that?

Comment: What is the purpose of the "big buffer"? What are you supposed to do with it? Transmit over the network or serial line or similar? Either way, I really recommend that you create a new structure, containing all the other structures. Then it's easy to create an instance of the new structure and to copy the contents of the smaller structures into it.

Comment: @EOF  Hmm.  I suppose I could do that, your solution didn't occur to me.  Is that what you would recommend?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  --  Yes, I'm actually trying to write a Ethernet/IPv4/TCP packet into a PCAP file, so I have five headers plus packet payload to manage.  When I post on SO, I try to reduce the problem down into a toy example

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude your idea of using a big "wrapper struct" is interesting to me.  Is that how you would solve this problem?

Comment: @Pete Because you want `Big Chunk of Memory is :: 6 bytes:`. There are 6 `int`s in total in the 3 structures, so to achieve this `sizeof(int)` must be 1.

Comment: @MikeCAT  Yes, I see that; thank you.  No, I don't care what sizeof( int ) is on my system; in fact, I see that ints are four bytes on my system.

Comment: @EOF Hey, I tried your "superstruct" idea - that WORKED.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expresspion `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. From that follows that `p + i` is equal to `&p[i]`.

This means that in your example `bigChunk+iter` will be the same as `&bigChunk[iter]`. And since `bigChunk` is an `int *`, the compiler will treat `bigChunk` as an  array of **`int`**, not as an array of bytes.

For the second structure, you will copy it to `bigChunk[8]` (assuming no padding) which is at a byte-offset of *32* (assuming a size of `4` for `int`) from the beginning of the memory. This is far beyond the offset to the second structure (it's byte-offset should be `8`).

Use `char *` as the type for `bigChunk` instead, to make it an "array of bytes".

Comment: Interesting!  So using sizeof( mystruct ) to iterate is backfiring on me for that reason.  Hmm.  If I wanted to make my solution work, it sounds like I should have iterated by num_of_elements_in_struct or something...

Comment: To anyone following this thread; Some programmer dude is right, I was using the wrong sizes to iterate.  When I used a debugger, I realized this was the wrong approach.